# $email->AddAttachment not attaching my file;

Tags: php

i have search for a solution here but have not found anything.

my code:

```
<?php

require_once('PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php');
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'my email address';
$email->FromName  = 'my name';
$email->Subject   = 'Possible positions';
$email->Body      = 'To whom this may concern';
$email->AddAddress( 'the to address' );

$file_to_attach = '/';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'Corporate.docx');
return $email->Send();
?>
```

[image]

the file is in my root dir same dir as this file auto-email.php which i run through a cronjob. the cronjob is running fine, it is just not attaching my file

Comment: Isn't it `AddAttachment($path, $name, $encoding, $type);` ? Did you try `->AddAttachment('Corporate.docx', 'Corporate');` ?

Comment: i just tried the above an it is not attaching my file and $path is root

Comment: For the `AddAttachment` method, the first parameter should be whole path to your file including the file name, not just the path to your file. The second parameter is for naming your attachment and it is optional.